# how to extract values of different field from the string in python

Tags: python

I am newbie in python, i have to extract values from a string:
str='x:10 y:12 time : 01/01/2010 11:55:55'

now i have to create a dictionary in which value is stored in such a way that:
x=10

y=12

time=01/01/2010 11:55:55

Please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything yet?
If not, here are some ideas...

**Using the built-in string manipulation tools**
For `x` and `y`:

```
>>> s = 'x:10 y:12 time : 01/01/2010 11:55:55'
>>> [pair.split(':') for pair in s.split(' ',2)[0:2]]
[['x', '10'], ['y', '12']]
```

and let's say that you then assigned that to a variable:

```
>>> lol = [x.split(':') for x in s.split(' ',2)[0:2]]
>>> d = {}
>>> for i,j in lol:
...   d[i] = int(j)
... 
>>> d
{'y': 12, 'x': 10}
```

For `time` maybe you can start like this:

```
>>> [term.strip() for term in s.split(' ',2)[-1].split(':',1)]
['time', '01/01/2010 11:55:55']
```

**Regular expressions**

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(\w+):(\d+)',s)[0:2]
[('x', '10'), ('y', '12')]
```

and then I'd probably just use `strptime()` for the final datetime portion:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime([term.strip() 
                      for term in 
                      s.split(' ',2)[-1].split(':',1)][1], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 11, 55, 55)
```